# Inflate method cannot be resolved while adding fragment onCreateView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to define an onCreateView for a fragment.

the code:

```
package com.example.weekplanner;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentChart extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=new inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_layout,container,false); //error on this line
        return view;




    }
}
```

but the `inflate` method cannot be resolved.

home_fragment_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. Have you tried a gradle sync? Can you assemble your app in terminal `./gradlew assembleDebug`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove new from inflater object

change this line

```
 View view=new inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_layout,container,false);
```

to this

```
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_layout,container,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

`inflator` is the object of `LayoutInflator` class that is already passed in the `onCreateView` method. Therefore, no need to use `new` keyword before it, because it's a object (not a class).
Thus, your code must be like this,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_layout,container,false); 
        return view;
}
```